# how to modify markup/template inside of DataList>ItemTemplate conditionally on data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, markup

Simple example: (.NET 3.5)

1. a SQLDataSource returning COL_A and COL_B columns,
2. a DataList control using the sqldatasource
3. inside a "item template" I want to have different sections depending on values of A or B:

   ```
   <ItemTemplate>
   <span class="item_title"><%# Eval("COL_A")%></span><br/> 

   <% if ( GET_DATA("COL_B") > 100 )   
   {
   %>
       <span>SOMETHING HERE</span>

   <%  }
   else
   {
   %>
       <span>DIFFERENT MARKUP HERE</span>
       <span>SOMETHING COMPLETELY DIFFERENT HERE</span>
   <%
   }
   %>
   ```

The question is:
What to use instead of GET_DATA to access value passed from SQL?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Conditional markup is not supported in ItemTemplate's. The best you can do here is to make your spans server-side and manipulate their Visible property:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <span class="item_title"><%# Eval("COL_A")%></span><br/> 

    <span runat="server" Visible='<%# (int)Eval("COL_B") > 100 %>'>
        SOMETHING HERE
    </span>
    <span runat="server" Visible='<%# (int)Eval("COL_B") <= 100 %>'>
        DIFFERENT MARKUP HERE
    </span>
    ...
```

Or you can wrap them in placeholders if you want to - might be a bit cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using scripting code like that probably isn't going to work.  I don't think you can mix script in with templated controls:  the script is interpreted at a different time from the databinding.

What you could do, though, is have a UserControl in your ItemTemplate that defines a property for  `ColB` and displays different markup depending on `COL_B`'s value.

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <span class="item_title"><%# Eval("COL_A")%></span><br/> 

     <uc1:UserControl1 runat="server" ColB='<%# (int)Eval("COL_B") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then in your user control markup you have two or more Panel controls:

```
<asp:Panel id="panel1" runat="server">
   <span>SOMETHING HERE</span>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="panel2" runat="server">
   <span>DIFFERENT MARKUP HERE</span>
   <span>SOMETHING COMPLETELY DIFFERENT HERE</span>
</asp:Panel>
```

... and then in your PreRender event in the user control code-behind (don't use Load, because your binding in the parent won't have happened yet):

```
 panel1.Visible = false;
 panel2.Visible = false;
 if(this.ColB > 100)
    panel1.Visible = true;
 else
    panel2.Visible = true;
```

You could promote those two Panel controls to your parent page, but then you'd have to do a .FindControl() call in the ItemDataBound event handler in order to change their properties, and extract `COL_B`'s value from the e.Item.DataItem property.  Lots of retrieving values and casting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input, it directed me towards the solution.

I, however, found a different solution that I will share here as it is neat and simple:

```
asp:PlaceHolder
```

Element can be nested multiple times to generate very clean HTML output.
Example below:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListLeft" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
  RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
    <ItemTemplate>                    
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" 
          Visible='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("COL_A", "{0}")) %>' >

            SOME HTML MARKUP HERE WHEN COL_A HAS A VALUE
            NOTE THE '!' IN CONDITION

        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server" 
          Visible='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("COL_A", "{0}")) %>' >

            SOME HTML MARKUP HERE WHEN COL_A IS NULL OR EMPTY
            eg. <span>Data is not available</span>

        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Again, Thanks for your time.

JK